# PL/SQL - to_char within DECODE

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a DECODE statement that works fine without putting to_char function in

```
Select DECODE(info.make_date, NULL,'SELECT ALL',info.make_date) as "listItemKey"
```

However I need `info.make_date` to be in a specific date format, so I use to_char

```
Select DECODE(info.make_date, NULL,'SELECT ALL',to_char(info.make_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')) as "listItemKey"
```

But when I do this I get `Unexpected '<'` as my JSON instead of the data I need to return. Is there a reason I can't set my `info.make_date` to the format I need here?

Comment: That's odd. Try a different date format or try `to_char(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')`, just to see if it changes anything.

Comment: This code works fine, though I personally would use `NVL` here instead for stylistic reasons.  Please post the rest of the code (where you transforming to JSON, etc).

Comment: @Dessma my make_date type was being set to a char somewhere else in the code, I only realized this after testing it with sysdate. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess an alternative could be as below. Please try and let me know if this works.

```
select case when info.make_date is null then 'SELECT ALL'
         else TO_CHAR (info.make_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
         end as "listItemKey"
```

However i would say to cast the date before using `to_char` with existing `DECODE`:

```
TO_CHAR (to_date(info.make_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY' )
```

Comment: Turns out I made a silly mistake and my info.make_date was being set to a char string. Thanks for the help